# ZipArchive Entry.FullName mangled

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, unzip

I have a zip file with an entry in it named:
`plätförm-sheet0.png`

When I load the bytes into memory, then loop each entry:

```
using (var data = new MemoryStream(archiveBytes))
{
    var archive = new ZipArchive(data);
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        entry.Name.Log();
        entry.FullName.Log();
```

It logs the values:

```
pl„tf”rm-sheet0.png
pl„tf”rm-sheet0.png
```

How can I retain the original file name `plätförm-sheet0.png` which exists in the zip file correctly before attempting extraction?

Comment: What makes you so certain the [ZipArchiveEntry.FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.fullname?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Compression_ZipArchiveEntry_FullName) code is bugged, and not your `Log()` method?

Comment: @CodeCaster when I extract the fle using the FullName it writes the mangled filename to disc

Comment: Yeah but you're not showing that code.

Comment: UTF8 encoding and UTF7 encoding comes out as `pl�tf�rm-sheet0.png`.  Is there any way to know the encoding of the zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify Encode when you read your zip

```
var archive = new ZipArchive(data , ZipArchiveMode.Read, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(437)));
```

Comment: _"Specify a value for this parameter only when an encoding is required for interoperability with zip archive tools and libraries that do not support UTF-8 encoding for entry names"_

Comment: Doing this creates the filename `pl�tf�rm-sheet0.png`

Comment: @TomGullen nice:)